ListView control not updating with data in Windows Forms application
I'm having an issue with a ListView control not updating with data in my Windows Forms application. Here's the relevant code:
// In the ProgramWindow form
public void UpdateDataListView(List<dynamic> AdvancedDataListResult)
{
    // Clear the existing items in the ListView
    DataListView.Items.Clear();

    foreach (var rowData in AdvancedDataListResult)
    {
        if (rowData != null)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
            item.Text = rowData.id?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
            item.SubItems.Add(rowData.serial_number?.ToString() ?? string.Empty);
            item.SubItems.Add(rowData.deceased_name?.ToString() ?? string.Empty);
            item.SubItems.Add(rowData.father_name?.ToString() ?? string.Empty);
            item.SubItems.Add(rowData.sure_name?.ToString() ?? string.Empty);
            item.SubItems.Add(rowData.mother_name?.ToString() ?? string.Empty);
            DataListView.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
    DataListView.Update();
}

The UpdateDataListView method is called from another form (AdvancedSearchForm) after retrieving the data from a search operation:
// In the AdvancedSearchForm
private void AdvancedSearchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string serial_number = Advanced_SerialNumber.Text;
    string deceased_name = Advanced_DeceasedName.Text;
    string mother_name = Advanced_MotherName.Text;
    List<dynamic> AdvancedDataListResult = search.AdvancedSearch(serial_number, deceased_name, mother_name);

    Program.UpdateDataListView(AdvancedDataListResult);
    this.Close();
}

The issue is that the DataListView control in the ProgramWindow form is not updating with the data from the search results, even though the UpdateDataListView method is being called with the correct data.
I've tried the following:
Ensuring that the AdvancedSearch method is returning the correct data (verified through debugging).
Calling DataListView.Refresh() instead of DataListView.Update() in the UpdateDataListView method.
Checking for control visibility and initialization issues.
None of these attempts have resolved the issue.
Additional Context:
The ProgramWindow form is already open and visible when the AdvancedSearchBtn_Click event handler is triggered.
The DataListView control is properly initialized and visible in the ProgramWindow form.
No data binding is used with the DataListView control.
Can someone please help me understand why the DataListView control is not updating with the data from the search results? Any assistance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
This draft provides a detailed description of the issue, the code involved, the steps you've already taken to try and resolve the problem, and additional context about the application. Feel free to modify or add any additional relevant information as needed.
Everything has been explained already in description of the problem.

is the lv  perhaos sitting in a tabpage?

No it's not sitting in any tabpage it's normally sitting in ProgramWindow form
